# NetSuite SuiteScript connection via rapidapi

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I am having issues using RapidApi within NetSuite. Has anyone done this before?

```
headersObj = [
    {
        name:"x-rapidapi-host",
        value:"hostishere"
    },
    {
        name:"x-rapidapi-key",
        value:"keyishere"
    }
];

response = https.request({
    method: https.Method.GET,
    url: "MyURLishere",
    headers: headersObj
});
```

I get the following return:

> error 400 message: Invalid API key. Go to https:docs.rapidapi.com/docs/keys for more info.

The API key is correct having tested through postman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header was missing "Accept":"application/json".

```
headersObj = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
     "Accept":"application/json",
     "x-rapidapi-host": "Myhost",
     "x-rapidapi-key": "Mykey",
     "Host": "host"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are making the call from within Netsuite you'd need to use their https library:

```
define(["N/https"], function(http){
    headersObj = [{ name:"x-rapidapi-host", value:"hostishere" }, { name:"x-rapidapi-key", value:"keyishere" }];
    var resp = http.get({url:'your url', headers:headersObj});
    // do something
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I am already calling the module, I just didn't include it in the example. Although I did change to use the https.get({url:'your url', headers:headersObj}) rather than https.request({ method: https.Method.GET, url: "MyURLishere", headers: headersObj }). I am receiving 401 unauthorized. message: Invalid API key. Go to https:docs.rapidapi.com/docs/keys for more info.